# angular 2+, using Promise doesn't give the result I am looking for

Tags: angular, promise, mean

I am calling the method createPublicPostContent() which is running a for loop that creates an array "tempArray"
However after the first loop (i=0) the Promise already resolves. How do I make sure that the promise only resolves when all the loops are finished?
I tried putting the resolve within the loop, this doesn't change the result.

```js
createPublicPostContent = (arrayOfPosts) => {
  var tempArray = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false;
    var i = 0;
    for (let key of arrayOfPosts) {
      if (key.coinCode == this.currentCoinCode) {
        steem.api.getContent(key.autheur, key.permlink,
          ((err, result) => {
            this.authorPostPublic = (result['author'])
            tempArray[i] = {
              "_id": key._id,
              "item1": this.postItem,
              "item2": this.postItem2
            }
            i++
            var size = Object.keys(this.publicPostGrade[0]).length;
          }))
      }
    }
    if (error) {
      reject('error')
    } else {
      resolve(tempArray)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You seem to have asynchronous function in your `for` loop. The `resolve` or `reject` should be done by the last callback finished (or use promises for these too if you don't want to handle that yourself), currently it is made after all the async functions are fired, but probably none responded with a result, so `i` is still at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this , as you are having multiple values

```
getItems(ids: number[]): Observable<Post> {
  return <Observable<Post>> forkJoin(
    ids.map(id => <Observable<Post>> 
          this.httpClient.get(`item/${id}`)
                 .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                          console.error('An error occurred:', err.error);
                        })           
  )
  ).pipe(concatAll());
}
```

Note: forkJoin wait for all request to complete and order of output is same as passed order. handle error in it properly as if one fails all fails . I suggest make use of `.catch()` function on request to avoid that

or

```
getItems(ids: number[]): Observable<Item> {
  return from(ids).pipe(
    mergeMap(id => <Observable<Item>> this.httpClient.get(`item/${id}`))
  );
}
```

Note : problem with mergemap  it order of request is not same as order of output. but there is way to handle it its given in post.

check this : [Practical RxJS In The Wild — Requests with concatMap() vs mergeMap() vs forkJoin()](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)  this post shows how you can handle multiple case , like scenario you are having.

Comment: Not implemented this yet, but I shall investigate!

Comment: @oudekaas - ok , you should go to post link where its given very much in detail, that will help you for sure as you requirement seems as same as given exaple, array of id and wait for all , even you can use forkjoin that is also given in post

Comment: that is great thank you very much, I did implement the below answers that work for me now, will yours be quicker?

Comment: @oudekaas - not comment on peformance but all request go parellel so it will become fast in that sense, another thing is code is very simple, right now you have lot of code which can be easily replace by code given by me and anyone work later on you code can easily understand , hope you got my point (it something easy to use and simeple why to reinvent wheel)

Answer (score 1):

```
createPublicPostContent = (arrayOfPosts) =>{
  var tempArray = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false;
    var i = 0;
    let loopCount = 0; // Number of requests sent
    let doneLoopCount = 0; // Number of received requests
    for (let key of arrayOfPosts){
      if (key.coinCode == this.currentCoinCode){
        loopCount++
        steem.api.getContent(key.autheur, key.permlink, ((err, result) => {
          doneLoopCount++
          this.authorPostPublic = (result['author'])
          tempArray[i] = { 
            "_id": key._id,
            "item1":this.postItem, 
            "item2" : this.postItem2
          }
          i++
          var size = Object.keys(this.publicPostGrade[0]).length;

          //If the number of received and sent are equal
          if(loopCount == doneLoopCount){ 
            if (error) {
              reject('error')
            } 
            else { 
              resolve (tempArray)
            }
          }
        }))
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented your answer and it works, but Pranay Ranabeat you to it by 1 minute. Is there a reason to use promises on the async steem.api.getContent method? Or not required since the loop just waits till the asynch methods are finished?

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching data from api that is asynchronous that's why, do the modifications as:

```
createPublicPostContent = (arrayOfPosts) => {
  var tempArray = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = false;
    var i = 0;
    var expectedApiCount = 0;
    var apiResponseCount = 0;
    arrayOfPosts.forEach(key => {
        if (key.coinCode == this.currentCoinCode) {
            expectedApiCount++;
            steem.api.getContent(key.autheur, key.permlink,
              ((err, result) => {
                apiResponseCount++;
                this.authorPostPublic = (result['author'])
                tempArray[i] = {
                  "_id": key._id,
                  "item1": this.postItem,
                  "item2": this.postItem2
                }
                i++;
                var size = Object.keys(this.publicPostGrade[0]).length;
                if (error) {
                  reject('error')
                } else if(apiCount == expectedApiCount) {
                  resolve(tempArray)
                }
              }))
        }
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: that works! When would I use something like this?: var getContent = async function(author, permlink) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    steem.api.getContent(author, permlink, function(err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
};

Comment: whenever you have only single api call.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can easily be solved by the async library. Just declare an async function in your component and await for your createPublicPostContent function to be resolved:

```
async myAsyncFunction () {

    const res = await createPublicPostContent()
    // this block is executed only after you get your promise resolved/rejected
    // in here you can use the resolved variable

}
```

One thing that I noted in your code is that you are resolving inside a forEach loop... You shouldn't do it, as this loop, as all others, is asynchronous. That means that the next loop is started imediatelly after your steem.api.getContent function is called, and doesn't wait for it to be completed. So your resolve/reject will be executed by the first answer you receive from your api, and it could be from the second, third or beyond calls, not mandatory from the first.

If you want to get all answers from your api and just after that do some action, you should store them in an array and then await for this whole array to be resolved using Promise.all(array). Something like this:

```
getApiData (key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (key.coinCode == this.currentCoinCode){
      var obj
      steem.api.getContent(key.autheur, key.permlink, ((err, result) => {
        this.authorPostPublic = (result['author'])
        obj = { 
          "_id": key._id,
          "item1":this.postItem, 
          "item2" : this.postItem2
        }
        var size = Object.keys(this.publicPostGrade[0]).length

        if (err) {
          reject('error')
        } 
        else { 
          resolve (obj)
        }
      }))
    }
  })
}

async createPublicPostContent (arrayOfPosts) {
  var tempArray = []
  for (let key of arrayOfPosts) {
    tempArray.push(getApiData(key))
  }
  var response = await Promise.all(tempArray)
  return response
}
```

By doing it like this you could also get rid of all those counters and array index tracking you created.